# If statement on DataTable field doesn't return true

Tags: c#, mysql

Is my `if` condition statement right? I'm trying to read the value of my `table column` that if it's contain a value of `1` then it will get the value of the book I'm searching.

The code doesn't have any errors. It compiles.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM tbladdbook WHERE fBarcodeNo LIKE '" + txtBARCODE.Text.Trim() + "%'";
cfgotcall.engageQuery(sql);

if (cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["fCurrentCopies"].ToString().Equals(1))
{
    txtTITLE.Text = cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0][1].ToString();
}
else 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Book already borrowed.");
}
```

Comment: You're trying to check if a string is equal to an integer. They're different data types.

Comment: What is "cfgotcall" ? show more code

Comment: @uɐpuɐɥƆ More code isn't needed. It's obvious why it doesn't work.

Comment: should i use `.Contains()`?

Comment: Side note: you should not, under any circumstances whatsoever, build a query from "unsanitized" user input like that, it's a security hole - look up SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It assumes that the database field type is a numeric field. As a side note, using SELECT * is bad. You should only retrieve what you need.

Do you want to check result == 1 or result > 0? In this scenario, where a library might have multiple books, I'd suggest you want to check > 0

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM tbladdbook WHERE fBarcodeNo LIKE '" + txtBARCODE.Text.Trim() + "%'";
cfgotcall.engageQuery(sql);

var result = cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["fCurrentCopies"];
if (DBNull.Value.Equals(result) || result == null) { result = 0; }
if ((int)result == 1)
{
    txtTITLE.Text = cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0][1].ToString();
}
else 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Book already borrowed.");
}
```

As a side note, everything in C# inherits from the "object" type. .Equals( ) accepts an object, not a string or an integer, etc. This is why you don't get a compliation error.

Comment: not numeric but float, i was thinking checking for < 0, if the `fCurrentCopies` goes `-1`, it will not be able to borrow that book

Comment: i get an error in `DBNull.Equals(result)`, it says `An object reference is required for the non-static field,method or property 'object.Equals(object)'`

Comment: @user3415509 Sorry, it's been a while since I've worked with SQL. I've updated it now. I'd recommend that fCurrentCopies should be an integer value, unless you're expecting to store half books! :)

Comment: i made it float because i have an Update method that has a `DISTINCT` sql in it so i need to use float hehe

Comment: Side note: it's a bad idea to build a query from unsanitized input like that because of the risk of a SQL Injection attack.

Answer (score 1):

`If` statement does not work because you compare `string` vs `int`. So it always return false.

```
if (cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["fCurrentCopies"].ToString().Equals(1))
```

1. `cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["fCurrentCopies"].ToString()` => It is a string. Maybe it is "1"
2. `1` is an integer (int)

=> To make it work correctly, you should change 1 (int) to "1" (string) like this:

```
if (cfgotcall.tbl.Rows[0]["fCurrentCopies"].ToString().Equals("1"))
```